# Multiple buttons to one circle

Tags: html, css, tizen

[image: Gear Screenshot]

I want to create a circle with distances with my 6 buttons. In the image you can see the result of my try but it doesn't look like a circle. I circled my problems with red. Below you can have a look on my HTML and CSS code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
     .container {
margin-top: 360px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
}

     .top-left {
     margin-top: -260px;
     margin-left: -20px;
     border-radius: 40px / 100px;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .top-right {
     margin-top: -260px;
     margin-left: 155px;
     border-radius: 40px / 100px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .bottom-left {
     margin-top: -160px;
     margin-left: -20px;
     border-radius: 40px / 100px;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .bottom-right {
     margin-top: -160px;
     margin-left: 155px;
     border-radius: 40px / 100px;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .top-center{
     border-radius: 440px / 220px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
     width: 270px!important;
     height: 70px!important;
     margin-top: -334px;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .top-center p {
     padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    }
    
    .bottom-center{
     border-radius: 440px / 220px;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
     width: 270px!important;
     height: 70px!important;
     margin-top: -64px;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .bottom-center p {
     padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    }
    
    .div-button {
     width: 168px;
     height: 92px;
     border: 2px solid rgba(77,207,255,1);
     background-color: transparent;
        color: rgba(77,207,255,1);
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: 100px;
     transition: all .3s linear;
    }
    
    .div-button p{
     margin-top: -10px!important;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .button-selected {
     transform: scale(0.8);
     border: none;
     background-color: rgba(77,207,255,1);
     color: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
 <div class="div-button top-center" id="top-center">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="div-button top-left" id="top-left">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="div-button top-right" id="top-right">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="div-button bottom-left" id="bottom-left">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="div-button bottom-right" id="bottom-right">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="div-button bottom-center" id="bottom-center">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you have static values for height and width. Why don't you just add an image/background that will outline the divs. Then position them in the container. That is the simplest solution. But if you don't want an image, then have fun playing with the border values.

Comment: I don't want an image. But I played arround with the border values and never received the expected result... ^^

Comment: You can use SVG and draw the path you like.

Comment: But you are already using an image, for the background. Why not use images for the buttons as well.

Comment: SVG sounds good :) No I'm not usign an image. This isn't a Web project it's a Tizen Gear project. My background is black. On my image you can see an emulator for a smartwatch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the svg route is the easiest way of reproducing what you want quickly.

However, liking the challenge, I used `overflow:hidden` and `position:absolute` to effectively mask out the different sections.

I created a pen [here](http://codepen.io/tenmilebrenty/pen/rWEXbR).

Any content you wish to place with inside the sections would need to go within the `.circle` div.

I hope this is along the lines of what you were wanting.

```css
.circle-container {
            position:relative;
            display:block;
            width:400px;
            height:400px;
            margin:auto;
        }
        
        .circle-crop-top {
            width: 100%;
            height: 25%;
            display:block;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        
        .circle-first-left, .circle-first-right, .circle-second-left, .circle-second-right {
            float:left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 25%;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .circle-bottom {
            width:100%;
            height:25%;
            display: block;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .circle-parent {
            position:relative;
        }
        .circle-parent p {
            position:absolute;
            text-align:center;
            margin:0;
        }
        .circle {
            width:396px;
            height:396px;
            border-radius:50%;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            border:2px solid blue;
            text-align: center;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .circle-first-left .circle {
            top:-100px;
        }
        .circle-first-right .circle {
            top:-100px;
            right: 0;
        }
        .circle-second-left .circle {
            top:-200px;
        }
        .circle-second-right .circle {
            top:-200px;
            right: 0;
        }
        .circle-bottom .circle {
            top:-300px;
            right: 0;
        }
        .circle-crop-top p {
            margin:0;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            padding-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            top: -2px;
        }
        .circle-first-left p {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 192px;
            height: 60px;
            margin:10px 0 10px 0;
            padding-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 23%;
            left:-2px;
        }
        .circle-first-right p {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 192px;
            margin:10px 0 10px 0;
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 23%;
            right:-2px;
        }
        .circle-second-left p {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 192px;
            height: 60px;
            margin:10px 0 10px 0;
            padding-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 48%;
            left:-2px;
        }
        .circle-second-right p {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 192px;
            margin:10px 0 10px 0;
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 48%;
            right:-2px;
        }
        .circle-bottom p {
            margin:0;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 76%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
        <div class="circle-crop-top">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Luzern</p></div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="circle-first-left">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Bern</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-first-right">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Zurich</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-second-left">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Basel</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-second-right">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Genf</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-bottom">
            <div class="circle-parent">
                <div class="circle"><p>Saas-Fee, Alpin</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how to make it responsive? :-)